# SwipeListView for delete particular row

Tags: android

I am new to this android and I am using swipe ListView for deleting a particular row. It's working properly. My requirement is when the user click the particular row in button that time only want to show swipe (right to left) with delete menu. If user click delete menu particular row should be deleted.

Comment: What is Swipe Listview ? do you mean Swipe refresh view ?

Comment: please use this example https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

Comment: you can use onClick Listener of listview raw .

Comment: how to hanlde swipe right to left in raw onclickListener?

Answer (score 0):

Use that [library](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) suggested by Divyesh Boda.

Use below code,for delete swipe listview row item, without loading activity

```
lvDetailMsgs.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index)    {

        switch (index) {

            case 0:

                hitSingleDeleteChat(position);              // onClicking the listview get position and hit json.

                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});


 private void hitSingleDeleteChat(final int position) {


    // inside method we are hitting json



    if(jsonObject.getString("Error").equals("false")){

        Log.e("ResponseThread", "test");


        messagesDetailList.remove(position);                  // At the success response, using the position we are removing the listview item 
        messagesDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```